# With RoR, where to define a custom method to be used in routes definition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I would like to use a custom method to build my routes.

Currently, I have something like this in my `routes.rb` file :

```
Foobar::Application.routes.draw do
  def my_custom_method
    # lot
    # of
    # code
  end

  pages = my_custom_method

  pages.each do |key, slug|
    get slug => 'pages#view', as: key, defaults: { slug: slug }
  end
end
```

But I'm sure it's not its place.

So where should I store this custom method ?

Which is the "good way" ?

Comment: It works if I create a file in `config/initializers` containing a "monkey patch" for `ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper` class. Is this an acceptable solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A working solution is to create the file `config/initializers/routes.rb` containing:

```
module ActionDispatch::Routing
  class Mapper
    def my_custom_method
      # lot of code
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Lib is a good place. It's even the choice of [Devise maintainers](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb).

Comment: I just tried. I have added a file routes.rb in the lib directory, but don't know how to load it. I tried to add the lib dir in `config.autoload_paths`, but it doesn't work. `rake routes` always says "undefined method my_custom_method"

Answer (score 1):

I would say the *ruby* way would be to extend the [ActionDispatch::Routing](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6767946374353f90ce05e68d38bcb93dcb8bae56/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing.rb) module with the added functionality.